# Running rspec request spec does not find the record which exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I am using Rails 5 (Ruby 2.3.3) for one of my projects. I have written a test using Capybara (capybara-wekbit) and RSpec.

I am testing a controller action using request spec. Here is the controller

```
class TimelineController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_child
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index    
  end

  private
  def set_child
    @child = Child.find(params[:child_id])
  end
end
```

Here is the test

```
RSpec.describe "Timeline", type: :request do
  it 'can visit the child timeline path', js: true do
    child = FactoryGirl.create(:valid_child)
    sign_in child.caregiver.user
    p child
    visit child_timeline_path(child)
  end
end
```

The `p child` line prints the following

```
#<Child id: 1, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, dob: "2018-06-21 00:00:00", caregiver_id: 1, doctor_id: 1, preferred_name: nil, gender: nil, street: nil, city: nil, province: nil, postal: nil, country: nil, email: nil, caregiver_relationship: nil, phone: nil, created_at: "2018-06-21 20:21:16", updated_at: "2018-06-21 20:21:16", avatar: nil, time_zone: "Pacific Time (US & Canada)", other_relationship: nil>
```

However, when RSpec calls `visit child_timeline_path(child)`, the test fails with the following error:

```
  1) Timeline can visit the child timeline path
     Failure/Error: @child = Child.find(params[:child_id])

     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Child with 'id'=1
```

I see the child record printed with the id. However, rspec is unable to find the record.

Here is the child factory (FactoryGirl)

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :valid_child, class: "Child" do |f|
    f.association :doctor
    f.association :caregiver
    f.dob Date.today
  end
end
```

Also, if it helps, here is the spec_helper.rb

```
require 'capybara/rspec'

Dir["./spec/support/**/*.rb"].sort.each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :request

  Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit

  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
      expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  # This option will default to `:apply_to_host_groups` in RSpec 4 (and will
  # have no way to turn it off -- the option exists only for backwards
  # compatibility in RSpec 3). It causes shared context metadata to be
  # inherited by the metadata hash of host groups and examples, rather than
  # triggering implicit auto-inclusion in groups with matching metadata.
  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction` means that the app under test and the tests need to share the same database connection in order to see created records. Unfortunately with Rails 5 (fixed in Rails 5.1+ obviating the need for database_cleaner at all) that isn't really supported between threads. This means that when running the `js: true` feature tests (which run the app in a separate thread) you need to change the strategy to :truncation or :deletion.  The suggested DatabaseCleaner configuration shows exactly what's needed - https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example